# Question on integral extension and minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain and $F$ be the quotient field of $R$.

Let $L$ be a finite field extension of $F$.

Let $\alpha\in L$ be integral over $R$ and $m$ be the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$. How do I prove that $m\in R[X]$?

Here's a proof given in Neukirch's textbook:

Since $\alpha$ is integral over $R$, there exists a monic polynomial $f\in R[X]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. Then, there exists $g\in F[X]$ such that $gm=f$. Since all the roots of $m$ are roots of $f$, it must be $m\in R[X]$.

I don't get this last line. Could someone please give me some more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Neukirch has left a gap here.

Let $\alpha_1 = \alpha, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$ be the roots of $m$.  As Neukirch states, these must also be roots of $f$ because of the equation $f = gm$.  Thus $\alpha_i$ is integral over $R$ for all $i$.  Write $m = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i X^i$.  By Vieta's formulas, the coefficients $b_i$ of $m$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $\alpha_i$, hence are also integral over $R$.  Since $m \in F[X]$ then $b_i \in F$ for all $i$.  Thus the $b_i$ are elements of $F$ and are also integral over $R$, so since $R$ is integrally closed in $F$ we conclude that $b_i \in R$ for all $i$.

Comment: Let $\bar{F}$ be an algebraic closure of $F$ such that $F\leq L\leq \bar{F}$. Let $\beta\in\bar{F}$ be a root of $m$. Then, $\beta$ is **not necessarily** integral over $R$, since $R$ is only integrally closed in $F$, not $\bar{F}$.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, if $\beta$ is a root of $m$, then it is a root of $f$.  $f$ is a monic polynomial with coefficients in $R$ and $f(\beta) = 0$, which shows that $\beta$ is integral over $R$.

Comment: Yeah, but $R$ is only assumed here to be integrally closed in $F$, not $\bar{F}$. So we cannot conclude that $\beta\in R$. Isn't it?

Comment: Oh now I see how your argument works. Thank you